# Laravel password reset token is different when it is saved in database

Tags: laravel

I am developing a Laravel application. I am now customising the password reset feature. There is an issue with retrieving the password reset token back from the database because the token string is changed when it is saved in the database from when it is generated.

I explicitly generate the password reset token like this

```
$token = app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($user)
```

Then, I tried to retrieve the password reset by using that token like this.

```
$password_reset = DB::table('password_resets')
            ->where('token', request('token'))
            ->first();
```

I cannot retrieve it. It always return null. Because the token value is different from when it was generated as in the screenshots below.

[image]

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why you're using `token` in the query?

Comment: Ok. I want to retrieve the user based on the token too.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your token generation.  generate your token by using str_random(60) and check. hope it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token gets hashed before it's stored in the database. It gets hashed in the `DatabaseTokenRepository` on line [110](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php#L110): `'token' => $this->hasher->make($token)`.

You won't be able to query by token. You would only be able to check a plain token value against a hashed value with the [`check`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Hashing/HashManager.php#L71) method in the `HashManager` class, for example.

Comment: Can anyone please tell how to get the DatabaseTokenRepository in the code (for example in Model)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you post a new question?

Answer (score -1):

Base on [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens)

your code should be something like this
`$token = app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($user)->accessToken`

Comment: The [`createToken`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L205) function that he uses doesn't have anything to do with Passport. It returns a string.